# TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'invalidatesTags')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

Hi guys I keep facing this error when using the rtk mutation

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'invalidatesTags')
here is my code

authSlice.ts

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react"
import { AUTH_BASE } from "../../constants/urls";

export const authSlice = createApi({
   reducerPath: "api",
   baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: AUTH_BASE, }),
   endpoints(build) {
      return {

         // sign in user
         login: build.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
               url: "/login",
               method: "POST",
               body
            }),
         }),
      }
   }
})


export const {useLoginMutation} = authSlice;
```

store.ts

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { authSlice } from '../auth';


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [authSlice.reducerPath]: authSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    const mids = getDefaultMiddleware().concat([authSlice.middleware])
    return mids
  }
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

and this how i use it in login.tsx

```
  const [login, result] = useLoginMutation()
  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const res: any = await login({ email: user?.email, password: user?.password })

  }
```

I can't seem to understand the issue

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might have forgotten to call unwrap() after login.
Should it not be:

```
const res: any = await login({ email: user?.email, password: user?.password }).unwrap()
```

[Source](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations)

> The "mutation trigger" is a function that when called, will fire off the mutation request for that endpoint. Calling the "mutation trigger" returns a promise with an unwrap property, which can be called to unwrap the mutation call and provide the raw response/error. This can be useful if you wish to determine whether the mutation succeeds/fails inline at the call-site.